# Why am I getting a Null Pointer Exception on this InputField?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If you could help me out here I'd appreciate it.

I have the script on the panel that the UI Elements are in and the UI elements are dragged into the appropriate boxes.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Login.Update () (at Assets/_Scripts/Login.cs:31)

public InputField emailInputField;
    public InputField passwordInputField;

```
private string email;
private string password;
public Button loginButton;
public Button createAccountButton;
private FirebaseAuth auth;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{

    emailInputField = GetComponent<InputField>();
    passwordInputField = GetComponent<InputField>();
    loginButton = GetComponent<Button>();
    createAccountButton = GetComponent<Button>();
}

void Update()
{
    if(emailInputField.text != "")
        email = emailInputField.text; <--This is where I get the error.
    if(passwordInputField.text != "")
        password = passwordInputField.text;
    createAccountButton.onClick.AddListener(() => CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password));
    loginButton.onClick.AddListener(() => SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password));
}
```

Comment: Okay, I've gotten the error to go away by removing the GetComponent<>() calls in the Start method. However, I'm not sure I understand fully why that was the fix. Any reasonable explanation would be helpful!

Comment: Because you have declared `public InputField emailInputField`, I suppose you drag & drop the correct inputfield in the inspector. By calling `emailInputField = GetComponent<InputField>()` in the `Start` method, you **override** the reference you have set in the inspector. I guess you have the `NullReferenceException` because `GetComponent<InputField>()` returns null, meaning there is no `InputField` component attached to the gameobject holding your `Login` script.

Comment: That sounds like the most probable answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

emailInputField.text != "" here your are checking only for value which is not Null, what happen if the value is null, so you are not passing any value to it,, thats why its gives you a null pointer excpetion